# Way to jump back to previous file/line on Mac ⌘[ not working in Android studio 4.1

Tags: android-studio

I updated the Android Studio to newest version (4.1) and it seems the key shortcut on Mac ⌘[ for moving to previous location stopped working. I tried to find it in preferences but have no idea how this is called. Do you know where to change it back?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems it was moved to different keyboard now: `Cmd + Alt + Left / Right`. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯